# How to check raycast target: gameObject.layer or gameObject.tag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using raycast to detect nearby objects, and I have to know if raycast hit the obstacle or another car. I see two ways of doing this but I don't know which one is better(more optimized). First way is to have two layers for obstacles and cars, set them both as layer mask for raycast and after hit check on which layer was the object. The other way is to have them both on the same layer and do raycast for one layer mask, but then I would have to check for the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run two tests, one for each method. Rays were casted from spining object onto other static and nonstatic objects, each test was run on the same quality setting, so i think the test is quite trustworthy. I measured after what time unity will render 30 000 frames. For checking layers it took 321 s and for checking tags 320. I don't think that there is any real difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say use tags for simplicity but I do not know which one is faster. In my previous projects I'v just used tags and I'd call this kinda function about 450 times per frame and I did not notice any performance loss (Did this both on my high end computer and a horrible school computer).

-Mitchell

Comment: Ok, I'm building game for mobile so performance difference may be more noticable. I will probably do some tests as you did.

Comment: @faken Yes if you are going to do test I highly suggest looking into the Unity Profiler [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) and the c# stopwatch class [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

this is not about which is faster but about what is their purpose.

what you should do is check for collision of a layer and then if you have different objects under same layer, check for tag. Note that the parameter for raycast is named layer.

Layer is just an integer and I would assume tag is using hash table, so both are fairly fast.

Conclusion: you should not always think in terms of efficiency but first in terms of purpose.